# Wordpress - saving custom fields data of custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Forgive me if this answer is easily found in the Codex function reference. I have looked at the reference page for `add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );` but I have not been able to find the information I need.

**What I have already:**

I've created a custom field for my custom taxonomy of a custom post type. This custom field is added both to the "add new" and "edit" contexts (see image links):

- http://screencast.com/t/CBmkyxrK
- http://screencast.com/t/BQacL9AL3G

Yay, the creation part works!

**What doesn't work:**

Unfortunately, I'm only able to save media links that added using the "edit" context. Media links added using the "add new" quick create tool are not being saved.

**Why it doesn't work**

If I take a look at the example I followed to create my custom meta field (https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/) you'll see that Pippin does not include a save action for the "add new" part, he only adds the field using `add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'pippin_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );`

---

I know that what I am missing is the WordPress specific syntax for saving actions in the "add new" context, and I know that it will be similar to the save action which is used for the "edit" context:

```
// add custom field to 'edit' and 'add new' contexts
add_action( 'affiche_edit_form_fields', 'affiche_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'affiche_add_form_fields',  'affiche_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );

// save field input
add_action( 'edited_affiche', 'save_affiche_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

**Reviewing the last line of the above code block, what is the equivalent string to** `'edited_[taxonomy_name]'` **for adding new (not editing existing) custom taxonomy entries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding new you need to use the `create_{$taxonomy}` hook

`add_action( 'create_affiche', 'save_affiche_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );`